# Nest.js Как отдавать HTML страницу только по Get запросу, защитив его Гуардом?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest.js

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтоб страница с админкой была недоступна кому попало. ServeStaticModule раздает всем всё. Меня это поведение везде устраивает, кроме ситуации с админкой. Я хотел бы страницу с авторизацией в админку давать всем, кто заходит на /admin, но вот всё остальное чтоб отдавалось клиенту только после ввода логина и пароля.
Интуитивно я думаю, что нужно сделать контроллер, защитить его гуардом, и если запрос поошел, то отдавать html страницу.
Но как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

### Мой способ реализации

В вашем случае было бы неплохо вынести `API` админ-панели в отдельное приложение `Nest`.

`$ nest generate app admin-panel`

Подобным способом построено [одно из моих приложений](https://github.com/GrapeoffJS/CRMServer/tree/refactoring/apps).

Я пришёл к этому, когда столкнулся с похожей проблемой, только в моём случае мне была нужна авторизация в CRM, но не нужна в admin-panel (авторизацию в админ панели планировалось сделать при помощи средств NGINX, так как в там не предусмотрено никакой регистрации)

### Ваш способ реализации

Можно реализовать подобное поведение несколькими способами:

1. Использовать [шаблонизаторы](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) и в контроллерах отдавать контент при помощи `@Render()`.
2. Также отдавать контент в контроллерах при помощи `res.sendFile()`.

Таким образом, вы сможете прикрепить к этим контроллерам `Guards`.

В случае с `ServeStaticModule` я не нашёл более удобного решения.

---

Но вообще, конечно, использовать `Nest` для раздачи статического контента достаточно странно и не удобно, как по мне.